# SVG is dying? What's next?

Tags: svg

I heard from more than a single source that SVG is dying, it is abandoned by Adobe.

How sad! What's will be next alternative to SVG?

Comment: I have never heard of Adobe being an important endorser of SVG. Did I miss something?

Comment: SVG isn't dying: 
http://raphaeljs.com/
http://google-code-updates.blogspot.com/2009/05/svg-open-2009-svg-coming-of-age.html

Comment: The five-year-anniversary of this question is near and SVG is still alive.... Mentioning Adobe i'm inclined to think jasonwel ment SWF, not SVG :-D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Check your sources.**

A lot of people want SVG "dead". A common way of getting something to happend is by spreading rumours that it has already happend. It's called a [self-fullfilling prophecy (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy). Don't buy into it, and please don't actually help those wanting it dead by spreading the rumor further yourself.

*Is SVG dead?*
No, it has just begun.

*What's next?*
HTML5, Canvas and SVG in one long glorious love-affair. Get your first-row tickets now!

(Actually here's a [youtube video of html5, canvas and svg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z73xtJN6IdA) showing off the infinite resolution inherent in vector graphics. Somewhat lame but *real*, unlike rumors.)

Comment: I'm not sure I would say this is a self-fulfilling prophecy - that would require a more widespread view that SVG is dying out, which really isn't the case.

Comment: Also, any significant reason for changing the accepted answer...?

Comment: Noldorin, please don't be mad at me. Your answer is actually better, but this one warn people to NOT spread the stupid rumor and I made it as the answer so that people can see this point easily.

I will 2 answers are allowed. 

My aplogy.

Comment: @jasonwel: Don't worry, I'm not at all irritated. :) I was just curious; your reason is fair enough.

Comment: I agree with both :) It's not a self-fullfilling prophecy.. yet, and lets keep it that way. (We have seen this happend way too many times in this industry to just ignore it. I just think its about time we start fighting the vaporware/antistandards-phenomena, that's all.) And +1 for your answer Noldorin! It's sensible and informative.

Comment: @0scar: Thanks. And yeah, I'm glad you're at least warning against this happening, though in fact, SVG seems to be growing in popularity more than ever now, as you point out.

Comment: Noldorin, 0scar: Both of you are great guy! Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 34):

SVG is an [open standard](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/), developed by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/). I really don't see it dying any time soon. Just because certain companies decide to drop its use for their commercial products (usually because they need, or feel they need, something more customised), it does not at all mean SVG will disappear on a more global scale.

At the moment, it's undoubtedly the most widely used vector graphics format on the web. Just take for example the images on Wikipedia - for almost all diagrams SVG is either used or there is a notice stating that it *should* be used. Many other open source projects endorse it in a similar way.

Now, the [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) markup language (part of WPF/Silverligtht) has been seen as a competitor to SVG by some, but truly they only overlap in functionality to a certain degree. (XAML supports lots of other things such as data binding, events, triggers, etc.) Indeed, the general use of XML is much restricted in that browsers don't natively support it (and can't properly, because of the fact that it's tightly bound to MS technologies). I would not even believe that it's strictly a direct competitor to SVG, nor that Microsoft have intended so.

To conclude, I don't think one can envisage SVG dying out until something clearly improved (and open-standard) comes along to replace it. As far as I know, there is nothing like that at the moment.

Comment: What a relief! Thank you Noldorin!!!

Comment: I would descrive Silverlight as more of a competitor for Flash rather than SVG, and I would even say that is Microsoft's intention.

Comment: No problem. :) And yeah, there's no need to worry here. The fact is that it's already a widely adopted standard, and isn't *very likely* to go away since it is standardised by W3C, though of course it may be succeeded by an improved format some day - there are no competitors currently.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, Silverlight is indeed a clear competitor to Flash. What I'm talking about is XAML, Microsoft's declarative (XML-like) format for displaying graphics and UI.

Answer (score 15):

[SVG (Viewer) was abandoned by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/) ages ago since most browsers support it natively.

Only IE is holding back the technology by not having native support.

**Update**: IE9 will have both native SVG support and native Canvas support! (Vista and above only though)

If you'd like to show your support for getting IE to support it natively add your vote and comments to these bugs.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=SVG

Comment: You meant SVG is still alive? Not going to be replaced by something else?

Comment: It took the IE team long enough to add proper PNG support... I don't know how soon they will get around to full SVG support.

Comment: AFAIK it is doing just fine (I use it). It works quite well in all browsers even if you need to use the unsupported plugin for IE.  Technology wise it works quite well and has few limitations. For non-text needs, CANVAS has some pretty compelling features too.  Unfortunately the chance of yet another vector markup language managing to take off and get support across all browsers is very unlikely.  IMHO badgering MSFT to start walking the walk and support SVG is the best thing you can do at this point.

Comment: @Noldorin - agreed MSFT moves incredibly slow on these things however evidence has proved that they do move on the items that developers/users complain about the most.  Since IE6 it was: SelectList Z-indexes, PNG Alpha, Descent CSS support, various .setAttribute() fixes, Operation Aborted fixes, getElementById fixes, etc.  Right now the main gripes are CSS rounded corner support, proper opacity support, and SVG support. Pls, pls, pls be part of the squeaky wheels that get MSFT to listen! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, CSS support and incorrect rendering is still perhaps the main problem of IE. I don't think I'll be happy with the state of web design until IE and all the other major browsers fully support CSS 3!

Comment: @Noldorin - agreed. Its a matter of LCD (Lowest Common Denominator) Firefox and Safari can support great new technologies but until IE catches up its often a moot point.  My only hope is that the non-IE browsers take enough marketshare that waiting for IE to implement a feature is no longer a concern.

Answer (score 3):

Bring back VML! Just kidding ;) I don't think SVG is dying, but <canvas>'s adoption for HTML5 seems like the way things are going on the web.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add my support for SVG. First, I believe that it is widely used in mobile technology though this is through conversations about 2 years ago rather than seeing code. It was one for the first languages developed by W3C to be used over-the-web and has been consistently supported for the last 10 years. I initially thought it would be a killer-app in 1998 and said so, especially since Adobe then had enthusiastic support.

Because SVG is a full XML dialect it can be easily mixed with other XML applications such as XHTML and MathML. It's possible to include XML information in SVG elements so that documents can be fully semantic (i.e. carry a data-meaning as well as a graphical one).

SVG is effectively feature-complete for a 2-D graphics language. There is no technical reason to invent anything else. It does high-quality rendering, animation and can support interaction through its own elements or through Javascript. It is therefore unlikely that major web software manufacturers will NEED to invent anything else.

The main problem is not that SVG is "dying" - it is not - but that it takes a long time for the various companies to converge. When they do I would expect SVG to emerge as a consensus.

Part of the problem is that graphics are not yet seen as a semantic problem - it's often "easier" to inflict a dumb animation on a client than to set up the infrastructure to send semantics over the web and repurpose at the client. But as the semantic web develops then standards such as SVG will be increasingly important. If, for example, you wish to mash-up geographical information then either you use a properietary solution such as GoogleMaps, or you look for a shared standard approach.  You can never count on free proprietary solutions in the long run.

Note also that in many areas which receive public funding there is an increasing drive towards Open standards and this is another reason why SVG is well positioned.

Answer (score 1):

Then there's this article posted Friday on Network World, titled [EC decision expected to force IE to better support standards](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/43851). In it, Håkon Wium Lie, Opera's CTO, states

> Second, due to the increased competition stemming from the ballot box, browsers will improve their support for standards. This will result in a richer, faster web. For example, I believe that Microsoft's IE will add support for SVG, a standard that all browsers but IE support.

Of course, it's in his best interest to see IE falling in line, but behind, his browser. He gets to be cutting edge, but part of a larger 'standards' crowd.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an question was asked before high res/ retina displays came to be the normal for mobile devices. SVG is having a big come back as vector graphics solves DPI issues on the web. You will be seeing more SVG on the web than before.

Even apple.com menu is svg now days!