# SVG alternatives?

Tags: svg

I read while Googling that SVG was "dead". Although I disagree, could anyone tell me more/future vector based format to represent 2d/3d graphics? What about VML? What format should I use to represent 2D and 3D graphics on Web?

I playing around with graphics on web and I would like to know if I'm working with an obsolete technology.

Comment: Since VML is so windows-centric I would avoid that, but SVG does have native support in Firefox, and doesn't appear dead, but you can do your vector drawing on the <canvas> tag, so in HTML5 there appears to be less demand to allow loading of SVG into this tag, which could appear to make them compete.

Comment: @James Black

Cant use HTML5 canvas, cause its not vector-based, its bitmap. (apart from other features i need)

And apart from VML, another/better one?

Comment: I'd ask for a `[citation needed]` on the death claim. Although admittedly SVG is not as widely supported as it should be, support is still slowly increasing (even IE9 will have it, that's quite something ;)).

Comment: Have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026875/svg-is-dying-whats-next Although it's over a year old I think it is still relevant. Since MS joined the W3C SVG WG it's likely that SVG support might get to IE.

Comment: Then, with these two reasons...i accept and close this question (post an answer to close it guys!)

Comment: what about 3D? SVG doesnt support it, isnt it?

Comment: Some time around 2006 Adobe abandoned its SVG viewer for IE. Some doomed SVG was dead. Lots of browsers have since then added native SVG support. Today SVG is not dead anymore.

Comment: Yes, SVG is not dead. Far from it. I'd say it's finding uses in more applications every day.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft is supporting SVG in IE9, and gave a detailed explanation of why they were doing it on the IE blog:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/svg-in-ie9-roadmap)

SVG's main advantage is that it becomes part of the DOM, so you can use CSS to style it and javascript to modify it. Canvas, by contrast, must redraw every frame completely. This makes canvas suited to spectrum analyzers, video processing, fast-paced games, and other non-gradual animations. SVG is better suited for gradual animations.

As far as 3D is concerned, the future is [WebGL](https://web.archive.org/web/20180928234102/http://learningwebgl.com:80/cookbook/index.php/WebGL:_Frequently_Asked_Questions), a thin shim over OpenGL ES, but it's far off. Microsoft has not committed to supporting it, and that means it's not going to be in IE9. Maybe IE10, maybe not.

If you do use SVG, I recommend using [svgweb](https://web.archive.org/web/20230901113359/https://code.google.com/archive/p/svgweb) to abstract away the browser differences (falls back to a flash applet on outdated browsers).

Comment: Obviously this whole question and answer is now only interesting for historical reasons. Just use svg people, no libraries needed.

Answer (score 6):

This post is rather late... but I think it is worth re-addressing, since your question has popped up again with all the html5 talk.

SVG is a vector drawing format that also supports animation, timing, and Javascript DOM support. In other words, it is a standalone format for static and dynamic vector graphics; you might say it is a web-focused (or screen-focused) alternative to EPS/PDF. The html5 canvas tag is not a format but a way to draw (static images) to the screen with Javascript — that is all; there is no competition between it and SVG, as they have entirely different purposes.

Most other vector "formats" involve plugins (Flash) or hardware support (webGL). Ironically, the VML format you mentioned is now deprecated in favor of SVG.

To answer your question: SVG is now the standard vector format for the web. Hopefully, in the near future, we will see it being used for video/animation as well.

Answer (score 6):

If it is SVG you are after the best way to go is [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/). It supports SVG better and it is a fraction of the size (4.5k gzipped) of Raphaël (31k gzipped). It also has a very intuitive syntax.

Answer (score 5):

All major browsers including ie9, firefox, safari and chrome are starting to supporting svg as part of the upcoming html5 standard. I wouldn't call that "dead"

Answer (score 5):

You can try the [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) JavaScript Library.

It is easy to implement and provides the same UI features as SVG (and more!).

Comment: That link is broken.  There is a [www.raphaeljs.com](http://www.raphaeljs.com/) which redirects to [GitHub.io](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)  The last commit was Feb 2017, which is recent, so looks like it's still actively developed.  Also, looks very interesting!

Answer (score 3):

2D: SVG
3D: X3DOM or webGL directly